# MongoDB aggregate last item matching condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wanted to get last value of a column matching certain conditions. If I use `$last` and `$cond`, it will give me the third parameter of the `$cond` almost always.

Eg: I have the following records

```
{uid:1,subject:"Maths",name:"Assignment 1",s_date:"2017-01-15 00:00:00"}
{uid:1,subject:"Maths",name:"Assignment 2",s_date:"2017-01-17 00:00:00"}
{uid:2,subject:"Maths",name:"Assignment 1",s_date:"2017-01-16 00:00:00"}
{uid:1,subject:"Science",name:"Assignment 1",s_date:"2017-01-11 00:00:00"}
```

I wanted to group these items to find out the date on which the last assignment for each subject is submitted. What I was trying to do was

```
collection.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
        _id: '$uid',
        science: { 
            $last: {
                $cond: [
                    { $eq: ['$subject','Science'] },
                    '$u_date',
                    null
                ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

In this case, if the last record for the user doesn't have the subject as "Science", I will always get null as output.

(I know this can be done by grouping with `_id:{'uid':'$uid','subject':'$subject'}.` This is a hypothetical example. my actual recordset is a bit more complicated.

Please understand that I don't want the final output in

```
{_id:{uid:1,subject:"Science"},'s_date':'2017-01-11 00:00:00'}
```

format but in

```
{_id:1,science:'2017-01-11 00:00:00',maths:'2017-01-14 00:00:00'}
```

format).

Please help me with an alternative way. I thought of using `$filter` and `$setDifference` but that will make it more complicated as the recordset is huge and query is generated dynamically by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $group twice.

```
collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { s_date: -1 } },
  { $group: {
    _id: { uid: '$uid', subject: '$subject' },
    s_date: { $last: '$s_date' },
  } },
  { $group: {
    _id: '$_id.uid',
    s_dates: { $push: { subject: "$_id.subject", s_date: "$s_date" } },
  } },
])
```

Result :

```
{
  _id: 1,
  s_dates: [
    { subject: 'Maths', s_date: '2017-01-17 00:00:00' },
    { subject: 'Science', s_date: '2017-01-11 00:00:00' },
  ],
}
{
  _id: 2,
  s_dates: [
    { subject: 'Maths', s_date: '2017-01-16 00:00:00' },
  ],
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I cannot use grouping based on the subject because there are multiple fields and multiple conditions based on these fields. That is the primary reason why am using $cond instead of directly grouping it with uid and subject.

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do then. Can you give an example of a case where grouping by uid and subject then by uid would not work?

Comment: Say, for example, Am storing User events in a collection. There will be multiple events and different fields associated with the events. For Eg: There will be a user logged in event, for which there will be logged in time as a field, and there will be user purchase event with the amount user spent as field. I have to write an aggregate query which will fetch me list of users who logged in within a week and purchased for more than $10. (Hypothetical again)

Comment: In the above condition, assume a situation where I want to fetch users who made their last purchase for a specific amount. (Let's say $1).